# Undefined local variable for hash in method ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, local-variables

for some reason I'm getting

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `states' for main:Object
```

though states is clearly defined. What is going on here?

In irb I added states in and accessed it fine using states[:CA] but when I put it in a method I got that error.

```
states = {
  CA: 'California',
  FL: 'Florida',
  MI: 'Michigan',
  NY: 'New York',
  OR: 'Oregon',
}

states[:CO] = 'Colorado'
states[:HI] = 'Hawaii'

cities = {
  CA: ['Alameda', 'Apple Valley', 'Exeter'],
  FL: ['Exeter', 'Amelia Island', 'Bunnell'],
  MI: ['Ann Arbor', 'East China', 'Elberta'],
  NY: ['Angelica', 'Apalachin', 'Canadice'],
  OR: ['Amity', 'Boring', 'Camas Valley'],
  CO: ['Blanca', 'Crestone', 'Dillon', 'Fairplay'],
  HI: ['Kailua', 'Hoopili', 'Honolulu'],
}

def describe_state state
  puts state
  description = "#{state.to_s} is for #{states[state]}."
  description << " It has #{citites[state].length} major cities:"
  cities[state].each do |x| ' ' << description end
end

puts describe_state :CA
```

Comment: Scope of your `states` variable is not visible to your method

Comment: So in ruby outside of methods, classes etc all variables that are set outside aren't available inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`states` is a local variable (because it starts with a lowercase letter). Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in (that's why they are called *local* variables, after all). So, `states` is defined in the scope of the script, but not in the scope of the method `describe_state`.

Method scopes don't nest, the only scopes that *do* nest are block scopes, so you would need to use a block. Thankfully, there is a method called `define_method` which creates a method from a block:

```
states = {
  CA: 'California',
  FL: 'Florida',
  MI: 'Michigan',
  NY: 'New York',
  OR: 'Oregon',
}

states[:CO] = 'Colorado'
states[:HI] = 'Hawaii'

cities = {
  CA: ['Alameda', 'Apple Valley', 'Exeter'],
  FL: ['Exeter', 'Amelia Island', 'Bunnell'],
  MI: ['Ann Arbor', 'East China', 'Elberta'],
  NY: ['Angelica', 'Apalachin', 'Canadice'],
  OR: ['Amity', 'Boring', 'Camas Valley'],
  CO: ['Blanca', 'Crestone', 'Dillon', 'Fairplay'],
  HI: ['Kailua', 'Hoopili', 'Honolulu'],
}

define_method(:describe_state) do |state|
  "#{state} is for #{states[state]}. " \
  "It has #{cities[state].length} major cities: #{cities[state].join(', ')}"
end

puts describe_state :CA
#=> CA is for California. It has 3 major cities: Alameda, Apple Valley, Exeter
```

Answer (score 3):

The method can't access the outside variables. You could use instance variables instead. From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables):

> Instance variables are shared across all methods for the same object.

Example:

```
@states = {
  CA: 'California',
  FL: 'Florida',
  MI: 'Michigan',
  NY: 'New York',
  OR: 'Oregon',
}

@states[:CO] = 'Colorado'
@states[:HI] = 'Hawaii'

@cities = {
  CA: ['Alameda', 'Apple Valley', 'Exeter'],
  FL: ['Exeter', 'Amelia Island', 'Bunnell'],
  MI: ['Ann Arbor', 'East China', 'Elberta'],
  NY: ['Angelica', 'Apalachin', 'Canadice'],
  OR: ['Amity', 'Boring', 'Camas Valley'],
  CO: ['Blanca', 'Crestone', 'Dillon', 'Fairplay'],
  HI: ['Kailua', 'Hoopili', 'Honolulu'],
}

def describe_state state
  description = "#{state.to_s} is for #{@states[state]}."
  description << " It has #{@cities[state].length} major cities: "
  description << @cities[state].join(', ')
end

puts describe_state :CA
#=> CA is for California. It has 3 major cities: Alameda, Apple Valley, Exeter
```

(I've fixed a minor bug in `describe_state`)

Answer (score 0):

states and cities are not defined in the function
pass them in like

```
def describe_state state, states, cities
 ..
end
puts describe_state :CA, states, cities
```

will work